# Wait for modeless dialog to close in vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dialog

In form I have one button which has functionality to pick up some data from (by mouse click)
Parent application.

I have handle for parent application handle, but even if i tried to bring it on top i am not able to do selection because form is modal.

Requirement here is **open modeless dialog and wait till it close.** other wise it goes further and executes functionality below.

Another option can be **open form as modal and at runtime change it to modaless**.

**But how to do it ? :)**

Comment: Are these windows the same application? Your description is slightly vague that it could imply separate processes.

Comment: It might be 'modal', but it's definitely 'modeless'.

Comment: main application-> one process, it opens another application in same process another application has form. And from this form I want to get input from Main application. hope you understand now :)

Comment: Application = Process, Form = Window.  I don't think you mean you are trying to communicate between Applications.  I think you mean you are trying to communicate between Forms.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming WinForms... when you create the dialog, hook into its `FormClosed` event. When it is closed, this event will fire and your original form will be notified (assuming the event handler is in the original form).

Something like:

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    private ChildForm _childForm;

    public void ShowChildForm()
    {
        _childForm = new ChildForm();
        _childForm.FormClosed += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("Child was closed.");
        _childForm.Show();
    }
}
```

That said, if you need to *wait* until it closes, then that sounds a lot like a ***modal*** dialog:

```
_childForm.ShowDialog();
```

Which will block on the main form until the child form is closed. No need to hook the closed event.

Comment: _childForm.FormClosed += (s, e) How to add event handler in parent if child is closed?

Comment: Cann't use _childForm.ShowDialog(); directly because I have one button which has functionality to pick up some data from (by mouse click) Parent application.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that mouse click, can you post some code to show why you can't use ShowDialog? It is the standard method to use in this situation.

Comment: my main application has some graphical object and i need to select it from form ,and update information on form, if i use showdialog directly on button click of the form I am not able to bring mail application window to forground to select from mouse as form is modal.

Answer (score -1):

Your question does not make complete sense but to try and answer it so far-

You can show a modal dialog using

```
Form1.ShowDialog
```

If you then need to show another modal dialog you can do this:

```
Form2.ShowDialog
```

You cannot show a *non modal* dialog when a *modal* one is current shown.